# Fluent Nhibernate, map column to method

Tags: c#, sql, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I'm pretty new to NHibernate in general, and I'm looking at an existing project. I have some Foo.cs with

```
public virtual bool IsTrue
        {get; protected set;}
```

And FluentMappings.cs has

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Foo> mapping)
{   
       mapping.Map(x => x.IsTrue).Formula("dbo.IsFooTrue(x, y, z)").ReadOnly();
}
```

From what I understand, this means that whenever someone wants to access the column "IsTrue", it instead runs some SQL code and dynamically generates the value.

Now, IsFooTrue is a SQL function defined in a separate file. The logic is quite simple, and I want to turn it into C# code. Let's say, for simplicity, the function always returns true.
How do I go about doing this? I tried removing the map and changing the Foo.cs class to something like

```
public virtual bool IsTrue
{
    get { return true;}
    protected set {}
}
```

But at runtime I get an exception "Invalid column name 'IsTrue'.\r\nStatement(s) could not be prepared." Is there a way to run C# code instead of SQL to generate this value?

Comment: Yes, just don't map the property - though it still needs to be virtual.

Comment: But that's what I did, I removed the mapping.

Comment: I've never used the auto-mapping, but take a look at this: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping#ignoring-properties, I'd imagine that you can then just implement the property however you wish.